# How to make a grid of points easily in Desmos

Tags: desmos

So currently I am Making a grid like this 
[image]

But obviously this is very inefficient to plot points in a grid like fashion

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/204990855-Lists ,
a comment by
Serge Ballif points to https://www.desmos.com/calculator/odm1auohqk

Inspired by that,
here is a rectangle

```
L=[0...(4*7)-1]
( mod(L,4) , floor(L/4) )
```

[image: robphy-desmos-grid]